# What is meant by $D \cos(z) = -\sin (z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In reading about some familiar cosine and sine identities extended to the complex plane, the following claims were made in Ahflors text on Complex Analysis:

$$
D \cos(z) = -\sin (z)
$$

and

$$
D \sin (z) = \cos (z)
$$

Exactly what is meant by the "$D$" above?  As far as I know it isn't stated in the text I'm using (Ahlfors).  Is this a standard symbol that I'm not aware of?

Comment: The derivative, $Df$ is an alternative notation for $f'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D$ is the differential operator, same as $\frac{d}{dz}$.